# jquery datatable with Express

Tags: datatables

How do I use jQuery DataTable plugin with Express - Node.js web application framework (ejs)? The docs show examples using php and I'm not sure how to adapt to my situation.

I need to load data from my postgresql database and display it to the user. They will need the ability to perform searches (I planned on using a form for this) and I need the ability to customize some of the returned data: some will have buttons along with returned data etc..

Comment: I'm currently playing with webix.com as recommended by another user.  So far, it seems to be going well and when I'm done, I'll past what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with jquery [datatables](http://datatables.net/).  Below is a sample server side script I created:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);
var conString = "postgres://dbname:password@localhost:5432/db";
var db = pgp(conString);



/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query);
    var sco; // shared connection object;
    var recordsTotal = 0;
    db.connect()
        .then(function (obj) {
            sco = obj; // save the connection object;
            return sco.query("select count(*) from provider"
            );
        })
        .then(function (obj) {
            //console.log('obj ' + obj[0].count);
            recordsTotal =  obj[0].count;
            return sco.query("select id, last_name as lastname, first_name as firstname from provider order by timestamp desc limit $1 offset $2 ",
                [req.query.length, req.query.start]);
        })
        .then(function (providers) {
            if (providers !== undefined) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "draw": parseInt(req.query.draw),
                    "recordsFiltered": recordsTotal,
                    "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
                    "data": providers
                }));
            }
        }
        , function (reason) {
            console.log(reason); // display reason why the call failed;
        })
        .done(function () {
            if (sco) {
                sco.done();
            }
        });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You may like support for [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.1.9.0) just added, which can simplify your code ;)